# How to combine filtered_contigs from different groups using scRepertoire package

Tags: r, tidyverse, seurat

I wanna combine different filtered csv files from two different groups. At first time, I just run these data separately based on these original csv files. I found this could caused a lot of repeated work for further analysis. Is there anyone can help me to solve out this hard nut for me? The details have been attached as below. Thank you in advance!

```
library(scRepertoire)
library(Seurat)
library(readr)
AA <- read.csv("/Users/Wawa/Desktop/VDJ/AA_filteredContigs.csv.gz")
HH <- read.csv("/Users/Wawa/Desktop/VDJ/HH_filteredContigs.csv.gz")
contig_list <- list(AA, HH)
combined_TCR_AA <- combineTCR(AA, 
                       samples = c("AA"),
                       cells = "T-AB")
combined_TCR_HH <- combineTCR(HH, 
                          samples = c("HH"),
                          cells = "T-AB")
combined_TCR_AA <- addVariable(combined_TCR_AA, name = "group", 
                        variables = c("AA"))
combined_TCR_HH <- addVariable(combined_TCR_HH, name = "group", 
                           variables = c("HH"))
names(combined_TCR_AA) = c("AA")
names(combined_TCR_HH) = c("HH")
str(combined_TCR_AA)
str(combined_TCR_HH)

Top10_clone_AA = lapply(combined_TCR_AA, function(x){
head(sort(table(x$CTaa), decreasing = T),10) / nrow(x)})
Top10_clone_stat_AA = do.call(cbind, Top10_clone_AA)
rownames(Top10_clone_stat_AA) = 1:10 
Top10_clone_stat_AA=reshape2::melt(Top10_clone_stat_AA)
colnames(Top10_clone_stat_AA) = c("ID","sample","Freq")
Top10_clone_stat_AA$group = substr(Top10_clone_stat_AA$sample,1,2)
head(Top10_clone_stat_AA)
ID sample        Freq group
1  1     AA 0.040865385    AA
2  2     AA 0.010416667    AA
3  3     AA 0.010416667    AA
4  4     AA 0.008814103    AA
5  5     AA 0.008814103    AA
6  6     AA 0.008012821    AA

Top10_clone_HH = lapply(combined_TCR_HH, function(x){
head(sort(table(x$CTaa), decreasing = T),10) / nrow(x)})
Top10_clone_stat_HH = do.call(cbind, Top10_clone_HH)
rownames(Top10_clone_stat_HH) = 1:10 
Top10_clone_stat_HH=reshape2::melt(Top10_clone_stat_HH)
colnames(Top10_clone_stat_HH) = c("ID","sample","Freq")
Top10_clone_stat_HH$group = substr(Top10_clone_stat_HH$sample,1,2)
head(Top10_clone_stat_HH)
ID sample        Freq group
1  1     HH 0.021621622    HH
2  2     HH 0.010810811    HH
3  3     HH 0.009009009    HH
4  4     HH 0.007207207    HH
5  5     HH 0.005405405    HH
6  6     HH 0.005405405    HH
```